# How to get a value from a callback statement in Swift

Tags: swift, callback, alamofire

I am using alamofire in my program to make a call for me and get data. It is stored inside a function that can be called from other classes. The function looks as so:

```
static func searchSong() {
    Alamofire.request(*urlhere*, callback: { response in
        parseData(request)
    }
}
```

And then the method parseData goes through what was returned to me. Now what I want to happen is for searchSong() to actually be able to return the data as I parse it in parseData. How can I get what I have at the end of parseData and return it in searchSong().

I have print statements telling me already I am getting a response and that parseData is working correctly, but I don't know how to get what I have at the end of parseData back to searchSong so that searchSong can return the desired information from where it is called.

Answer (score 0):

Make your searchSong() function take in a callback (with the requirement that the callback take in params of type parseData) and then when the alamofire request is complete call the callback and pass the call back the parseData. I'm sure you already know but that alamofire request is Asynchronous. The most standard way of handling these kinds of problems is to just call a callback.

Answer (score 0):

Alamofires' calls are made asynchronously what means that your searchSong function return value will be always Void. 
If you want to "return" the response value, add a callback as parameter to searchSong

```
func searchSong(returnCallback: (Any) -> Void){
    Alamofire.request(*urlhere*, callback: { response in
       // Any is the type of your returning element.
       returnCallback(/* resposne or wathever you want to return */)
    }
}
```

Then wherever you are calling searchSong, you will have a structure like this:

```
self.searchSong { (response) in
    /* code here */
    // here on response you have the request returning value
}
```

Note that all this process is asynchronous that's the way Apple handle HTTP requests so Alamofire follows that.